# Why does my componentWillMount get called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `componentWillMount` gets called but i don't get why en how to fix it.
My code is the following:

```
componentWillMount(): void {
        apiClient
            .get("module/menu/top/get")
            .then(response => {
                ReduxService.dispatch(setMenus(response.data));
            })
            .catch(() => {
                message.error("Het is niet gelukt de menu items op te halen! Herlaad de pagina.");
            });
    };

    getFooterItems = () => {
        apiClient
            .get("module/menu/footer/get")
            .then(response => {
                ReduxService.dispatch(setMenus(response.data));
            })
            .catch(() => {
                message.error("Het is niet gelukt de menu items op te halen! Herlaad de pagina.")
            })
    };
```

This is my render:

```
<Tabs type="card" onTabClick={this.getFooterItems}>
```

So i want my componentWillMount to get called like its supposed to.
But when i use the onTabClick to switch between tabs (Ant.Design) i want to use the this.getFooterItems function but not the componentWillMount

EDIT: FIXED IT HAD FOR BOTH MY DISPATCHES THE SAME SetMenus

Comment: `componentWillMount` is a lifecycle method and gets called automatically when a component is rendered (https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class). What is exactly what you want to have differently?

Comment: Then i want to stop my componentwillmount with rendering when i click on the tab

Comment: componentWillMount will be called only first time when component is rendered and it will not be called on tab click. If it is happening you are doing something wrong on tab click.

Comment: your `Tab` component is probably being unmounted as a result of that function and then recreated again. But it's hard to know without knowing what's happening in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentWillMount` is deprecated, you should be using `componentDidMount` for api calls.

`componentWillMount` is react lifecycle method which gets called 1 time automatically when your component renders. This is not custom function.
More about lifecycle [methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

If you want to execute this code on say click on some button, put the code inside a function and call that function on `onClick` of that button.

Hope that helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

**componentWillMount** is executed before the component is rendered. if you want to run any execution before the component is displayed, **componentWillMount** is your method.
If you want this execution on tab click, then put this code inside **getFooterItems** method.

Answer (score 0):

**componentWillMount** is a deprecated lifecycle method. In the latest version of react it's available as **UNSAFE_componentWillMount**. If you want to call some API when the component renders **componentDidMount** is the lifecycle method you want to use.

If you want to call a method when you switch tabs, you should use the appropriate handler for it

hope it helps